# jQuery click event not trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer, jwplayer6

I'm using jwplayer latest version 6.8. I try to use jQuery to call function when user clicked my logo in the player but it doesn't work.

This is the logo's image tag of the player in HTML:

```
<img class="jwlogo" id="container_logo" src="..." />
```

This is the jQuery function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){            
    $("#container_logo").click(function() { 
      alert('Work!');
    });               
  });                  
</script>
```

This is the test page: http://vt-test.co.nf

Any help please?

Comment: @gibberish is correct. `#container_logo` doesn't exist in the page when the ready event is called, so that selector doesn't work and no click handler is attached.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using an outdated jQuery version?

Comment: are you having licenced version

Comment: @Damien Black hm...Are you using Mac? Because i tried Firefox, IE, Chrome & Window safari on my Windows 8.1 here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery 1.3, try using [`jQuery.live`](https://api.jquery.com/live/) like this:

```
$('#container_logo').live('click', function() {
    alert('Work!');
});
```

Note:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated.

**Edit**

I found a solution using the onReady event of JWPlayer:

```
$(function() {            
    jwplayer("container").onReady(function() {
        $('#container_logo').click(function() {
            alert('Works!');
        });
    });
});
```

You can see it in action in [`this jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/pDhWj/)
However, I suggest you to update your jQuery version and use [`jQuery.on`](http://jsfiddle.net/pDhWj/)

Comment: `.live()` has been deprecated, use `.on()`.  OTOH, looking at OP's source I now realize the OP is using an outdated version of jQuery (1.3.1) so you may be right ! `**Yes, .on entered jQuery-land as of version 1.7, so .live is the right choice here.**`

Comment: live() is deprecated. You should use `on` like @gibberish said

Comment: However, I believe .live/.on should bind to the element above that one: `$('#container')`, no?

Comment: @MarianoCordoba I tried your suggestion by still no luck: http://vt-test.co.nf/MarianoCordoba/ Any advice?

Comment: @MarianoCordoba Gosh...onReady! You're so brilliant! How stupid i am! :( Thanks a lot! It's worked! :)

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, i would recommend you to update your jQuery version or use `jQuery noConflict`.

Then, you would need to surround your image with a wrapper div and delegate the click event using [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

**HTML:**

```
<div id="myWrapper">
    <img class="jwlogo" id="container_logo" src="..." />
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myWrapper").on("click", "#container_logo", function() {
        alert("Work!");
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you checked OP's jQuery version? There is no `.on` in version 1.3.1

Comment: And a good answer it is. +1 (which will need to happen in 2.5 hours as I'm out of votes for now...)

Comment: @martynas I tried your suggestion but no luck: http://jsfiddle.net/46BrE/2/ Any advice?

Comment: I will have a look tomorrow - I have a deadline for today

Comment: I see you found a solution. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the upper right link worked for me.

However, try:

```
$(document).on('click', '#container_logo', function(){  
    alert("hello"); 
});
```

If the elements are injected, that will do the trick.

Since you are using an older version of jQuery (1.3.1), you must use `.live()`, like this:

```
$(document).live('click', '#container_logo', function(){  
    alert("hello"); 
});
```

Also note that you can bind the wrapper to the DOM element into which the code is injected:

```
$('#container').on('click', '#container_logo', function(){  
    alert("hello"); 
});
```

Comment: on is throwing error Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'

Comment: @gibberish Weird...Are you using Mac? Because i tried Firefox, IE, Chrome & Window safari on my Windows 8.1 here.

Comment: @gibberish I tried your suggestions by still no luck: 1st example: http://jsfiddle.net/46BrE/ 2nd example: http://vt-test.co.nf/gibberish and 3rd example: http://jsfiddle.net/46BrE/2/ Any advice?

Comment: @Love I tried it again just now. When click the upper-right corner, I am redirected to this site: http://www.jwplayer.com/learn-more/. When click on center button, the video plays. I will review your jsFiddles and post results.

Comment: @Love When click on 1st example, logo in upper right corner it again hyperlinked successfully to http://www.jwplayer.com/learn-more/. In your 2nd example, clicking the JWPLAYER example works, but the blender logo at bottom does not (!). In the 3rd example, the upper-right corner logo also takes me to the learn-more website. I am using Windows 7 with the current version of Google Chrome.

Comment: @gibberish oh...no..i think it's misunderstanding here. the redirect to URL jwplayer.com/learn-more is a default function of the logo. What i'm testing the jQuery function is alert('work'), just same as the test logo below the player.

Comment: @Love I now understand what you mean. Yes, that's a tough one. You are trying to override the javascript embedded with the injected player. I tried a number of things myself, but no success. I suggest asking another question where you specifically ask how to override the javascript injected with the player. Sorry that I cannot be of more assistance.

Comment: @gibberish Thanks gibberish, it's solved now. Thanks a lot for your help. :)

Comment: @Love How did you solve it? Very curious... thought I tried everything. If possible, please post an answer with the solution and accept it as the answer for this question.